# Group by query - Not a single group by function?

Tags: .net, sql, database, oracle

I have a table like this

```
column1 column2 column3

abc      xyz      4
def      ghi      3
abc      xyz      6
abc      xyz      1
jkl      mno      4
```

Expected Result after query

```
column1 column2 column3

abc      xyz      11
def      ghi      3
jkl      mno      4
```

My Query is like below:

```
select column1, column2, count(column3)
from
    (select ......) as column1, 
    (select ......) as column2, 
    (select ......) as column3) 
group by column1, column2, count(column3)
```

I get this error "not a single-group group function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SUM` and you must remove the `count(column3)` in the `group by` and if you really get the columns as results from sub-queries it might need to rather look like this:

```
select column1, column2, sum(column3) 
from   (
         select
             (select ......) as column1, 
             (select ......) as column2, 
             (select ......) as column3
           from dual
       )
group by column1, column2
```

otherwise you would need to repeat the entirety of the sub-query select in the `group by`. In your query you say `FROM (select .......) as column1` but that means that the subquery is called `column1` which does not work. The selected columns in the subquery could be addressed by using the prefix `column1`. For example if you say `FROM (select x from test) t1` then you can address x by writing `t1.x`.

but if you have a simple table as you describe above the correct statement is

```
select   column1, column2, sum(column3) from mytable
group by column1, column2
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using SUM

```
SELECT  column1,
        column2,
        SUM(column3)
FROM    YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY column1,
        column2
```

Comment: I have used sum function as you mentioned, but getting this following error "not a single-group group function"

Comment: Use the entire query. The key is that your SELECT columns must match your GROUP BY, i.e. `column1, column2` with the additional `SUM(column3)`. http://ora-00937.ora-code.com/

Answer (score 0):

by using simple query you will get answer as u like

```
  select col1, col2, sum(col3) from test
  group by col1,col2
```